# How to not send bots message edit discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I have a message edit log but I want to stop sending the log if a mobs message was updated, I tried a few codes like

```js
if(bot.oldMessage.content.edit()){
return;
}
```

It showed and error

```js
cannot read property 'edit' of undefined
```

I then removed edit then content was undefined. The code for the message update is below.

**The Code**

```js
module.exports = async (bot, oldMessage, newMessage) => {
     let channels = JSON.parse(
    fs.readFileSync('././database/messageChannel.json', 'utf8')
  );
  let channelId = channels[oldMessage.guild.id].channel;
  let msgChannel = bot.channels.cache.get(channelId);

  if (!msgChannel) {
    return console.log(`No message channel found with ID ${channelId}`);
  }
if (oldMessage.content === newMessage.content){
  return;
}

  let mEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(oldMessage.author.tag, oldMessage.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
  .setColor(cyan)
  .setDescription(`**Message Editied in <#${oldMessage.channel.id}>**`)
  .addField(`Before`, `${oldMessage.content}`)
  .addField(`After`, `${newMessage.content}`)
  .setFooter(`UserID: ${oldMessage.author.id}`)
  .setTimestamp()
  msgChannel.send(mEmbed)
  }
```

How would I stop it from sending the embed if a bots message was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a really simple check will resolve this issue. In Discord.js there is a user field that tells you if the user is a bot or not.

In fact, it is really recommended you add this in the "onMessage" part of your code as it stops other bots from using your bot, this is to make sure things are safe and no loopbacks/feedbacks happen, either way, you don't want a malicious bot taking advantage of your bot, which can get your bot in trouble too.

Here is what you want to do;

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
```

What this code specifically does is check if the message's author is a bot, if it returns true, it will break the code from running, if it returns a false, the code continues running.

You can do the same if you want to listen to bots ONLY by simply adding a exclamation mark before the message.author.bot like this;

```
if (!message.author.bot) return;
```

It is also possible to see what other kinds of information something holds, you can print anything to your console. For example, if you want to view what a message object contains, you can print it into your console with;

```
console.log(message) // This will show everything within that object.
console.log(message.author) // This will show everything within the author object (like ID's, name, discriminators, avatars, etc.)
```

Go ahead and explore what you can do!
Happy developing! ^ -^

Answer (score 0):

That is really easy to do. All you need to do is check if the author of the message ist a bot and then return if `true`. You do that like this

```
if (oldMessage.author.bot) return;
```